# Calling Property Let from inside Class

Tags: vb6

Is there a way calling a Property Let method from inside the same class?

Like this function `SetConnectionDetails`. But this one gets a Compile error: Invalid use of property...

```
Public Sub SetConnectionDetails(ByVal strServer As String, ByVal strDatabase As String, ByVal strUser As String, ByVal strPassword As String)
    Server (strServer)
    User (strUser)
    Password (strPassword)
    Database (strDatabase)
End Sub

Property Let Server(ByVal value As String)
    lServer = value
End Property

Property Let User(ByVal value As String)
    lUser = value
End Property

Property Let Password(ByVal value As String)
    lPassword = value
End Property

Property Let Database(ByVal value As String)
    lDatabase = value
End Property
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You call it as a normal property/variable:

```
Public Sub SetConnectionDetails(ByVal strServer As String, ByVal strDatabase As String, ByVal strUser As String, ByVal strPassword As String)
  Server = strServer
  User = strUser
  Password = strPassword
  Database = strDatabase
End Sub
```

Or, more explicitly:

```
Public Sub SetConnectionDetails(ByVal strServer As String, ByVal strDatabase As String, ByVal strUser As String, ByVal strPassword As String)
  Me.Server = strServer
  Me.User = strUser
  Me.Password = strPassword
  Me.Database = strDatabase
End Sub
```

Note that I've removed the () around the values/parameters is they shouldn't (normally) be there, and [may catch you out later](http://hashvb.earlsoft.co.uk/Brackets_around_procedure_parameters).